# Enable/Disable the anchor tag (similar to twitter bootstrap .disabled class)

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, anchor

I have a page that lets the user edit the content of the page using an html editor widget. There is an anchor tag for edit. I want to enable and disable the anchor tag for edit based on the mode of operation. If the user is not in edit mode, enable the anchor tag, else disable it. I have seen the anchor tags with .btn .disabled classes being disabled using the twitter bootstrap. I would like the similar feature that works across multiple browsers but without using the bootstrap.

Comment: So, what is our deadline on this?

Comment: it's on the sprint. So, at most 2 weeks..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To disable the default behaviour of an anchor tag, you can use:

```
$("a").click(function(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
});
```

To unbind it, this should work:
`$('a').unbind('click');`

Comment: that will prevent the default behavior, buut it will not stop any attached click handler...

Comment: All this does is not to go to the path indicated. However, every time I click the anchor tag, it goes through the function call. I want to remove the click event. I don't know why, the unbind is not working for me.

Comment: I'm marking this answer correct. However, it is not exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is the *right* way to do it but I'd have

```
<a href="whatever">Link Text</a><span>Link Text</span>
```

and simply use css/jquery to display/hide the link or the span as appropriate.

There may well be a more elegant way to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: Currently, I have done like you said; hide and show the anchor tag. I was just wondering if there is a better way to do this.

Comment: Define "better". There are some "cleverer" ways by wrapping your event attachment to allow you to attach and detach all the click events on the anchor but it adds a lot of complexity. Always remember to [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle) :D

Comment: For the scenario, by better I mean not hiding the anchor.